# Does it matter which side I favor during the truce negotiations?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I managed to get General Tullius and Ulfric at the table in High Hrogthgar, negotiating the terms of a truce, so that I could solve the Dragon problem.

Now, there are several choices I can make during the negotiations, each favoring one of the opposing sides. I chose more or less randomly, as I haven't chosen any side in the civil war yet.

What consequences do my choices here have for the future?

Answer (score 2):

Which ever side you choose to favor doesn't really matter for the main story line. The only time where these decisions really affect the game is when you choose a side and begin to fight the other. Even then, the main thing that happens is that who is in control of some of the strongholds is changed.

Answer (score 2):

If you force a side to cede control of a hold, the other will gain control of it. This has a few effects.

A hold changing sides will replace the Jarl with either an Empire or Stormcloak loyalist as appropriate. This removes any bounty the Dovahkiin has in that hold. It does not reset progress with Thane-related quests which will continue with the new Jarl

If and when you do the Civil War questline, the quest for any hold your faction holds is skipped. This means you may have to do more or fewer quests before the final battle for Solitude/Windhelm. The War Hero achievement is tied to taking Markarth/Riften- it is permanently missed if your side takes it in this negotiation.

Finally, if the Dovahkiin has chosen a side and brokers a favourable treaty for their side, Ulfric/Tullius will give them a levelled weapon as a reward. They will chastise the Dovahkiin if they negotiated a bad deal but there is no further effect.